# Abstract Management component for Joomla

Tags: joomla, components, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I'm looking for an abstract management component for Joomla **2.5**. Google guides me to [this page](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/surveys/9954), which Joomla has deleted it.

Do you know any free component? (or I have to write myself...)

Answer (score 0):

J! Research may be helful for you if you want to organize abastracts but not run a conference.
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/living/education-a-culture/bibliography/5909